# exec code in original local scope of frame

Tags: python, debugging, exec, frame

I've written a remote Python debugger and one of the features I need is to execute arbitrary code while stopped at a breakpoint. My debugger uses the following to execute code received from the remote debugger:

```
exec (compile(code, '<string>', 'single') , frame.f_globals, frame.f_locals)
```

This works fine for the most part, but I've noticed a couple issues.

1. Assignment statements aren't actually applied to the original locals dictionary. This is probably due to the fact that f_locals is supposed to be read-only.
2. If stopped within a class method, accessing protected attributes (names beginning with double underscore) does not work. I'm assuming this is due to the name mangling that Python performs on protected attributes.

So my question is, is there a way around these limitations? Can I trick Python into thinking that the code is being executed in the actual local scope of that frame?

I'm using CPython 2.7, and I'm willing to accept a solution/hack specific to this version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Assignment statements aren't actually
>   applied to the original locals
>   dictionary. This is probably due to
>   the fact that f_locals is supposed to
>   be read-only.

Not exactly, but the bytecode for the function will not look at `locals`, using rather a simple but crucial optimization whereby local variables are in a simple array, avoiding runtime lookups.  The only way to avoid this (and make the function **much**, **much** slower) is compiling different code, e.g. code starting with an `exec ''` to force the compiler to avoid the optimization (in Python 2; no way, in Python 3).  If you need to work with existing bytecode, you're out of luck: there is **no** way to accomplish what you desire.

> If stopped within a class method,
>   accessing protected attributes (names
>   beginning with double underscore) does
>   not work. I'm assuming this is due to
>   the name mangling that Python performs
>   on protected attributes.

Yep, so this issue *does* allow a workaround: prepend `_Classname` to the name to mimic what the compiler does.  Note that double-underscore prefixes means **private**: **protected** would be a *single* underscore (and would give you no trouble).  Private names are specifically meant to avoid accidental classes with names bound in subclasses (and work decently for that one purpose, though not perfectly, and not for anything else;-).

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but thanks for the clarification Alex.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood you correctly, but `exec` does populate the `locals` parameter with assignments inside the code:

```
>>> loc = {}
>>> exec(compile('a=3', '<string>', 'single'), {}, loc)
>>> loc
{'a': 3}
```

Perhaps `f_locals` doesn't allow writes.

Comment: In my experience, f_locals is writable, but it seems to be a copy of the original locals() dictionary. So any changes made to it, won't affect the original scope.

Answer (score 0):

> to execute arbitrary code while stopped at a breakpoint ... Can I trick Python into thinking that the code is being executed in the actual local scope of that frame?

The Python debugger, pdb, allows this. For example, let's say you are debugging the file `tests/scopeTest.py`, and you have the following line in your program, where the variable hasn't been declared in the program itself :

```
print (NOT_DEFINED_IN_PROGRAM)
```

so that running the code `python tests/scopeTest.py` would result in :

```
NameError: name 'NOT_DEFINED_IN_PROGRAM' is not defined
```

Now you would like to define that variable when stopped at that line in the debugger, and have the program continue executing, using that variable as if it had been defined in the program all along. In other words, you would like to effect the change within that scope, so that you can continue execution with that change permanent. It is actually possible :

```
$ python -m pdb tests/scopeTest.py
> /home/user/tests/scopeTest.py(1)<module>()
-> print (NOT_DEFINED_IN_PROGRAM)
(Pdb) 'NOT_DEFINED_IN_PROGRAM' in locals()
False
(Pdb) NOT_DEFINED_IN_PROGRAM = 5
(Pdb) 'NOT_DEFINED_IN_PROGRAM' in locals()
True
(Pdb) step
5
```

Pdb does this through a `compile` and `exec` in its `default` function, which does the equivalent of :

```
code = compile(line + '\n', <stdin>, 'single')
exec(code, self.curframe.f_globals, self.curframe_locals)
```

where `self.curframe` is a specific frame. Now, `self.curframe_locals` is not `self.curframe.f_locals`, because, as the `setup` function says :

> ```
> # The f_locals dictionary is updated from the actual frame
> # locals whenever the .f_locals accessor is called, so we
> # cache it here to ensure that modifications are not overwritten.
> self.curframe_locals = self.curframe.f_locals
> ```

Hope that helps, and is what you meant!

Take note that, even then, should you want to, for example, replace a function in the context of the program being debugged with a monkey-patched version, such as:

```
newGlobals['abs'] = myCustomAbsFunction
exec(code, newGlobals, locals)
```

the scope of the `myCustomAbsFunction` is not going to be the user program, but is going to be the context of where that function was defined, which is the debugger! There is a way around that too, but as it wasn't specifically asked, it is left as an exercise for the reader, for now. ^__^